# Linq multiple fields from one list distinctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having issues with a single query, I am attempting to take a list of objects (`opList`) and extract 2 UID's per object to create a distinct list for another query.

```
DataContext.Where(x => opList.Select(y => y.UIDFirst)
                           .Union(opList.Select(o => o.UIDSecond)).ToList()
                           .Contains(x.uid)).ToList();
```

while each of the selects work by themselves, and the union works to join the lists to a unique list (tested in imediates window) an exception is thrown when processes the statement as a whole.

any ideas on what I did wrong;

```
  {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'DataContext.Class.Operation'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}
```

Comment: I'm still confused: is `DataContext.Where` correct? Shouldn't you call `Where` on some table in that `DataContext`? And I think EF does not support `ToList` inside that `Where` clause, but I'm not too experienced in EF.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var uids = opList.Select(o => o.UIDFirst)
                 .Concat(opList.Select(o => o.UIDSecond)
                 .ToList();

var result = DataContext.Where(dc => uids.Contains(x.uid)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your statement on a certain `DbSet` contained in the DataContext, not on the DataContext directly.

```
DatContext.SomeDbSet.Where(x => /* ... */ );
```